# Does JSONModel have $top and $skip like OData?

Tags: sapui5

In my app I'm reading data from a JSON file and creating a model from it like this

```
var myModel = new sap.ui.model.JSONMOdel("pathToJson");
```

I have 300 values but I only want to read 50, is there a way to do that. I know I can use $top and $skip to select a specific set of values using OData. The API provides the function myModel.loadData() which contains a parameter oParameters but I don't know what I can pass in. Does anyone know if this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON model is a client-side model. This means that all the data is loaded at once with a single request. In the standard implementation, it has no methods for reading paged JSON contents (with top / skip or any other name you might give them).

You have said that you have a JSON file that you are loading. So such a paging does not even make sense from a technical point of view. This is because you cannot (easily) load a portion of a static file with client-only code (especially JSON, which is not valid if you are reading a fragment of it).

If you actually just want to store a segment of the file in the model, you can simply read the whole file with [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and then [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?v=example) the array.

If you actually have a RESTful web service, then the paging mechanism should be part of this service (e..g it should have some path or query parameters for specifying the paging parameters). This service should return a valid JSON document for each call. On the client side, you can use such a service with the help of some functions (e.g. in the controller):

```
onInit: function () {
    this.setModel(new JSONModel([])); // initially an emty array
},

//call this method when you want to read a page
onReadDataPage: function (iTop, iSkip) {
    // use jQuery.ajax or jQuery.get to read a "page" of data; e.g.
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "your service path",
        data: {
            top: iTop,
            skip: iSkip || 0
        },
        success: this.onDataReceived.bind(this)
    });
},

onDataReceived: function (aData) {
    var oModel = this.getModel();
    oModel.setData(oModel.getData().concat(aData);
}
```

If you want to use this in combination with a List with the growing feature, then you will need to create a new type of model - which is not trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Serban Petrescu
I ended up creating several json files and calling them separately to simulate this.